# split action bar doesn't appear?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

i want to make action bar top and down in android 4.03  make code but when i run it it doesn't appear , i don't know what is wrong , i search for reson before asking here but i didn't find anything 
here is menu/style.xml code:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item 
   android:id="@+id/first"
   android:icon="@drawable/cat"  
    />
<item 
   android:id="@+id/first"
   android:icon="@drawable/phone" 
    />
<item 
   android:id="@+id/first"
   android:icon="@drawable/music" 
    />
<item 
   android:id="@+id/first"
   android:icon="@drawable/dialog" 
    />
<item 
   android:id="@+id/first"
   android:icon="@drawable/file"
    />
<item 
   android:id="@+id/first"
   android:icon="@drawable/contact" 
    />
<item 
   android:id="@+id/first"
   android:icon="@drawable/contact" 
    />    

</menu>
```

manifest code:

```
<activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".CalendarActivity" 
            android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
            >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


     and activity code:
      @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
         super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
         MenuInflater i=getMenuInflater();
         i.inflate(R.menu.style, menu);
         return true;
    }
```

because this is first use to android 4.0 i'm a little confused, why my items in black color i can't see them ??

Comment: Does the application actually start? you have the same id for all the views in the menu, I feel like I'm stating the obvious but I'm curious about it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set `android:minSdkVersion="14"` in your manifest? Because `android:uiOptions` is compatible with older versions of Android so you don't see any error!

Remember also that

> Android adjusts the action bar's appearance in a variety of ways,
>   based on the current screen size

See [Using split action bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#SplitBar) for more info.

Comment: yes,i put android:minSdkVersion="15" in manifest , i think it's not the problem i think it's something in the code

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add
    android:showAsAction="always"
to every item in the menu xml.